# Post job-interview: are my actions and the timeline outlined reasonable?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, hiring-process, feedback

**Question**:
Could you please provide some feedback on the steps I have taken so far and plan to take after my job interview? Should I wait a little longer?

**Context:**

- Contacted on LinkedIn by an internal recruiter of the company.
- Telephone interview went very well and I learned a lot about the role and company.  Also received very good feedback during the interview.
- Online interview scheduled with the hiring manager. At this point, my recruitment point of contact changes to another internal recruiter.
- Interview rescheduled on the day. OK.
- No sign of manager halfway through the interview. I call the recruiter and understand the manager was running late. It also later turns out I was provided the incorrect meeting link.Manager spends more time telling me about the company and role, all great. They say they are very impressed by my CV but only ask one question.
- I ask about next steps and they advise they will send their feedback to the recruiter. I am advised
  after following up with the recruiter that I should expect feedback within 2 weeks.
- I sent a thank you note to the recruiter who originally contacted me on LinkedIn. No response (not that it was expected.)
- 3 weeks have passed and the recruiter has not responded to my follow up email.

**Actions and Timeline**

1. 3 weeks from interview date: email recruiter again for feedback.
2. 3.5 weeks from interview date: send a note to the recruiter on LinkedIn who initially approached me
   and ask them to get in touch for feedback.
3. 1 month from interview date: leave a review online about my experience (offer or no offer).

**Thought process:**

Although the role and company themselves are great, I have written off the role in my mind or working for the manager who interviewed me. This experience left a really sour taste and now I intend to leave positive/ negative interview reviews for employers going forwards. Even though I have a job in hand, I understand job hunting especially during COVID is incredibly stressful. The intention of this question is to understand if I am following the right steps to share my interview experiences, whilst giving the employers a fair chance to provide feedback in good time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action plan looks great, but before all that (what you should have done long back already), if you have a direct or contact number, give them a call. It may just so happen that one person in the process is missing / out of office for some reason (sudden leave, absence etc) and cannot take the process forward, and your application / feedback is stuck. If you do not have a specific number, call up the general helpline and ask to be connected to the recruitment department.

If you don't get any update, do all the planned items anyway.

Last but not the least: don't get your hopes too high. Usually a month after (and in some cases, even after 2 weeks), it's a lost case. If you need a new job, search for others, or continue with the current one.